# Theorem proof of local inclusions

Tags: real-analysis

Please help prove the following theorem:

> Let $f$ be a map from $R^l$ to $R^m$ that is continuously differentiable on an 
>   open set that contains a point $p.$ Suppose that the linear map $J_f(p)$ is 
>   one-to-one ($J_f(p)$ is the Jacobi matrix of $f$ at $p$). Show that 
>   there are open neighborhoods $V, W$ of $f(p), p$ and a continuously 
>   differentiable map $t$ from $V$ to $W$ that has a continuously differentiable 
>   inverse such that $t(f(x_1,..., x_l))=(x_1,..., x_l, 0,...,0).$

I know I need to do the following:
By composing with a linear isomorphism of $R^m$ we can assume that $J_f(p)$ maps $(x_1,..., x_l)$ to $(x_1,..., x_l, 0,...,0).$ Denote the first $l$ coordinates of $(x_1,..., x_n)$ by $x$ and the other $m-l$ coordinates by $y.$ Let $F(x,y)=f(x)+(0,y)$; this is a self-map of $R^m$ that is continuously differentiable near $(p,0).$

But how I can show that $J_F(p,0)$ is nonsingular, and apply the inverse function theorem to find the inverse of $F$ near $F(0,p)?$ And compose that inverse with $F(x,0)=f(x)$ to finish the proof?